# How to show thumbnail image in my project when i am storing image on google drive

Tags: java, spring, jsp, google-app-engine

I am uploading documents and storing on google drive successfully. now i want to fetch only thumbnail of documents to show at the place of download link. please suggest me how i do? This is my controller code which i am using for upload document.

```
'`@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView uploadFile(@RequestParam(value = "ddid", required = true) Integer ddid,
        @RequestParam(value = "catageryId", required = true) Integer catageryId,
        @RequestParam(value = "document", required = true) GMultipartFile document[], HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse resp) {

    DdeDriveDocuments ddeDriveDocuments = new DdeDriveDocuments();
    if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) && document != null) {
        for (GMultipartFile gdocument : document) {
            try {
                boolean user = true;
                List<DdeDriveDocuments> dds = ddeDriveDocumentsService.fatchData(ddid, catageryId);
                for (DdeDriveDocuments file : dds) {
                    System.out.println(file.getDocument_name());
                    if (file.getDocument_name().equals(gdocument.getOriginalFilename())) {
                        user = false;
                    }
                }

                if (user == true) {
                    ddeDriveDocuments
                            .setDocument_name((gdocument.getName() != null ? gdocument.getOriginalFilename() : ""));
                    System.out.println(gdocument.getOriginalFilename());
                    ddeDriveDocuments.setDocument_created(new Date());
                    ddeDriveDocuments.setCatagery_id(catageryId);
                    ddeDriveDocuments.setDd_id(ddid);
                    ddeDriveDocuments.setDd_uuid(GeneralUtil.getUUID());

                    Lawyer googleAuthToken = lawyerService
                            .getAuthorisedUserToken(Configurator.getInstance().getDriveAccountEmail());
                    if (googleAuthToken != null) {
                        // upload file in drive
                        if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request) && document != null) {

                            // It's value either we need to get from form.
                            String description = "Testing";

                            File file = DriveService.uploadDocumentToDrive(googleAuthToken, gdocument,
                                    ddeDriveDocuments.getDocument_name(), description);



                                File thumFile = DriveService.getFileById(googleAuthToken, file.getId());

                                System.out.println("thab url"+thumFile.getThumbnail());

                            System.out.println(file.getThumbnailLink());



                            if (file != null) {
                                ddeDriveDocuments.setDocument_drive_id(file.getId());
                                ddeDriveDocuments.setThumburl(thumFile.getThumbnailLink());
                                ddeDriveDocuments = ddeDriveDocumentsService.create(ddeDriveDocuments);
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Autorised token not available for configured drive account.");
                    }

                }

                else {
                    System.out.println("wroung Input");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/al/lawyer/ddfiles/" + ddid + "/" + catageryId);
}`'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use the Drive REST API method [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get). The result of that method contains *thumbnailLink* but according to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files) it is 'a short-lived link to the file's thumbnail. Typically lasts on the order of hours.'

Alternatively if you just want to show something pretty you can get the content-type or extension of the file and display a generic thumbnail for all files of that type. I suggest this because in my experience the drive api is not one of the apis that respond fast.

Alternatively or additionally you can / should cache the thumbnail in your application, reducing the count of drive api requests and thus improve your page performance.

Comment: Ok can you suggest me how i can cache the thumbnail in my application. or can you please provide me any example i am using gmultipart file.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma the above code works for uploading, which is the first step. Now you need to fetch the information for the uploaded file. There's an example of how to do that here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get. The easiest way of caching is to simply download the thumbnail and save it like "fileid_thumb" somwhere and upon the next request you check if such a file exists before actually requesting the thumbnail.

Comment: successfully download the document but unable to get thumbnail of document.

Comment: what are the values of the properties "thumbnailLink",  "thumbnail.image" or "thumbnail.mimeType" ?

Comment: all three properties have the same value?

Comment: Thank You i got it. using thumbnailLink . Thanks a lot

Comment: Need more help.  at the time of downloading the file i am successfully get thumbnailLink but at the time of uploading i am getting thumbnailLink only for images not for other type of documents please help me. I want thumbnailLink at the time of Uploading to store in link in database than i can easily display on front hand.

Comment: Please see above code. and please suggest me as soon as possible.

Comment: First off: bad idea. The link to the thumbnail is a temporary link (approx. life time is 7 hours, to your thumbnails are gone by tomorrow) You need to download and save the thumbnail itself. Secondly: If Drive does not provide a thumbnail you're simply out of luck, there is no thumbnail available this way. Google drive can't read all kinds of files thus it will fail to generate thumbnails for the majority of file types. Please see 'Alternatively [...]' in my original answer to prettify it anyway.